# Master Page doesn't grab styling for contentPlaceHolder

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

This is the first time I have worked with Content.
I created a full aspx page with all styling and etc and it looks like this with all styling/bootstrap and etc:

[image]

Using the first page as a reference, I separated the code from it and copied it into the Master Page and moved all the navbar code into Default.aspx page.

When I create a content master and add the code it shows up like this:

[image]

I am unsure why the styling and etc doesn't show up. Something must be organized wrong?

I even tried adding css directly into the Master but still css didn't work.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site1.master.vb" Inherits="CherylsGroupWeb.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet nofollow" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link href="Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu-content li').click(function () {
            $('#menu-content .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
            $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link
        });     
</script>

<style>
   <!-- put all css here to test as well -->
</style>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="topContent" runat="server">
           <a href="Default.aspx">Master Pages Tutorials</a>

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML in the browser. Does everything appear as expected? Do the paths to the CSS files look correct? What happens if you watch the Network tab of your browser's developer tools as you load the page?

Comment: It's probably an ID that got renamed to `topContent_menu-content` or something like that. Check the HTML.

Comment: I checked an example online and I see that they condense the second aspx page inside a content which I didn't do. I also tried and reformatted based on an example and for some reason their's work. will post my code

Comment: Problem is related to path. Where are css? Where is master page? Where is content page? Use tilde in relative path and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly I formatted wrong, but by coping the structure of an example into a new Master and adding the content around my Default.aspx it displayed it. So I removed the `<a>` for my Default.aspx

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="GroupWeb._Default1" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="topContent" runat="server">
        <!-- my nav bar code --->
</asp:Content>
```

Master

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id='mainBody'>
<h1>
    How to use Master Pages in ASP.NET
</h1>
<br />
<b>This is a Master Page Content.</b>
<br />
<br />
<div>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="topContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <!-- ContentPlaceHolder is used to enable the pages which uses this page as master page, to place their contents -->
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```